# How to do factorial analysis for a non-normal and heteroscedastic data?

Tags: r, nonparametric, experiment-design, heteroscedasticity

I designed a field experiment with 4 independent factors but data is not normal and heteroscedastic.  Friedman test (agricolae package) from R only fits for rbd.  Can anybody suggest how to analyze my data please?

Answer (score 2):

Package [vegan](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/softhelp/vegan.html) implements some permutation testing procedures using a distance based approach.  For factor analysis, you should take a look at section 5 of the [documentation](http://cc.oulu.fi/~jarioksa/opetus/metodi/vegantutor.pdf).  There's also more information in the paper:

- [On distance-based permutation tests for between-group comparisons](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/19673867) (Reiss et al, 2010)

You might also be interested in skimming this table:

- [Choosing the Correct Statistical Test](http://bama.ua.edu/~jleeper/627/choosestat.html)

Answer (score 1):

The **Skillings-Mack test**  is a general Friedman-type test that can be used in almost any block design with an arbitrary missing-data structure. It's part of the `asbio` package for R, and there's a user-written package `skilmack` for Stata.

Skillings, J. H., and G. A. Mack. 1981. [On the use of a Friedman-type statistic in balanced and unbalanced block designs.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1268034) *Technometrics* 23: 171-177.

Aho, K. [`asbio`: A collection of statistical tools for biologists.](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/asbio/) Version 0.3-24. 2010-9-18. *Comprehensive R Archive Network (CRAN)* 2010-09-19.

Chatfield, M. and Mander, A. [The Skillings–Mack test (Friedman test when there are missing data).](http://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0167) *Stata Journal* 9(2):299-305.

Answer (score 0):

As you suggest you "designed" an experiment, it would be better if can you give a description of your design and data set. Even if the data is heteroscedastic and non-normal, probably some variable transformations might help and you may be able to take advantage of the design. The t-test is fairly robust to the normality assumptions.

Comment: hi S.  yes we did transformed the data, then we standardize against the largest value, then transformed the standardized value

Comment: but was your design a Randomized Complete Block Design?